# How to set button.value by switch with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying (*in Visual Studio 2015 to build a windows app*) to recognize button's onclick event and change it's value with the following code.

This is the default html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PlanetHome Proxy Switch</title>

    <!-- WinJS-Verweise -->
    <link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>
    <script src="AcidJs.ToggleSwitch/lib/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="AcidJs.ToggleSwitch/classes/ToggleSwitch.js"></script>

    <!-- App2-Verweise -->
    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
// Toggles the passed button from OFF to ON and vice-versa.
        function toggle(button) {
            switch (button.value) {
                case "ONN":
                    button.value = "OFF";
                    break;
                case "OFF":
                    button.value = "ONN";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="win-type-body">
        <form action="">
            <input type="button" id="1" value="ONN" style="color:blue"
                   onclick="javascript:toggle(this);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But Button's value doesn't change.
What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Again: I'm trying this in Visual Studio 2015 to build an Windows App.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mn98ux0r/1/ ?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Maybe you have a JavaScript error somewhere else on the page that's causing this code not to run?

Comment: I'm trying this with visual studio to create a windows app. but the button doesn't change

Comment: You might want to try and add a closing `</form>` tag after the input.

Comment: done but no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to toggle the button value

HTML

```js
function toggle(button) {
    switch (button.value) {
        case "ONN":
            button.value = "OFF";
            break;
        case "OFF":
            button.value = "ONN";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Setting button.value by switch with onclick event</h1><br>
     <input type="button" id="1" value="ONN" style="color:blue"  onclick="javascript:toggle(this);">
</body>
  </html>
```

```
 <input type="button" id="1" value="ONN" style="color:blue"  onclick="javascript:toggle(this);">
```

JS

```
 function toggle(button) {
    switch (button.value) {
        case "ONN":
            button.value = "OFF";
            break;
        case "OFF":
            button.value = "ONN";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 41, column 2 in ms-appx://2413b856-ca73-48a0-867c-4798f4ac1486/js/default.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Put the script tag below the input tag, or add a document.ready event and place this code in there...

Comment: I did. nothing changed. If I change the name of the function to xy, it is the same state. is it correct, that there is no error, if html can't find any function?

Comment: use onclick="javascript:toggle(this);" in HTML button control

Comment: I've updated my question. Maybe now you'll find what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this. keep your js code in head portion.

```
<html>
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
// Toggles the passed button from OFF to ON and vice-versa.
        function toggle(button) {
            switch (button.value) {
                case "ONN":
                    button.value = "OFF";
                    break;
                case "OFF":
                    button.value = "ONN";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body">
<form action="">
<input type="button" id="1" value="ONN" style="color:blue"
onclick="javascript:toggle(this);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really have no idea, but this isn't working as well

Comment: @DavidSeek Are you sure you are pressing the button? Because if i copy this exact code into a index.html file, and open it locally, it just works.. I believe we need more information as to what your environment is

Comment: the button does blink